# How to identify user in safari web push notification

Tags: safari, apple-push-notifications

I am using APNS to send web push notification to safari. In the web:

```
window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission(
        'https://domain.example.com', // The web service URL.
        'web.com.example.domain',     // The Website Push ID.
        {userId: '111111'}, // Data that you choose to send to your server to help you identify the user.
        checkRemotePermission         // The callback function.
    );
```

In the backend, I add the endpoint:

POST:

`webServiceURL/version/devices/deviceToken/registrations/websitePushID`

DELETE:

```
webServiceURL/version/devices/deviceToken/registrations/websitePushID
```

POST:

```
webServiceURL/version/log
```

But those APIs are called without any cookie, the BE just receive the device token without any information about which user is login.

I try to add {userId: '111111'} to the data in FE to hope that it is sent to BE, but I receive nothing in BE.

Does anyone have a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

There should be another endpoint for downloading the push package.

POST

```
webServiceURL/version/pushPackages/websitePushID
```

In the method called by the above endpoint, you should be able to get the {"userId": "111111"} in the request body.

Also try changing {userId: '111111'} to {"userId": "111111"}